# Can I add a seed member on version 3.0 or 3.4 to a MongoDB replica set with members that are on version 2.6.8?

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset, sql-update, database

I want to upgrade all members to 3.4, however, I want to be able to switch back to 2.6.8 if anything goes wrong.  In order to do this, I was hoping to add a new member 3.0 or 3.4 member to the existing replica set (on 2.6.8), replicate the data, then break it out and create a separate replica set on 3.4.  After breaking out the synced up 3.x member, I would add further 3.x members to it and switch my app to use the new replica set. If the app breaks, I am planning to switch back to the older replica set.  I read that replica set members can be on different versions.  I am having trouble locating information on specific versions and potential issues.  Also, the reason I keep mentioning 3.0 as well as 3.4, is because when I started planning, the latest version was 3.0, I also heard that I have to upgrade members incrementally, so from 3.0 to 3.2 to 3.4. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be documented in Mongo Release Notes for 3.0, 3.2 and 3.4.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-upgrade-replica-set/

> "upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.4, you must be running a 3.2-series release.
>
> To upgrade from a version earlier than the 3.2-series, you must successively >upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 3.2-series. For example, if >you are running a 3.0-series, you must upgrade first to 3.2 before you can >upgrade to 3.4."

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-downgrade/

> "To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.2, you must be running a 3.0->series release.
>
> To upgrade from a 2.6-series release, you must upgrade to the latest 3.0-series >release before upgrading to 3.2. For the procedure to upgrade from the 2.6->series to a 3.0-series release, see Upgrade to 3.0."

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/

> "To upgrade an existing MongoDB deployment to 3.0, you must be running 2.6. If >you’re running a version of MongoDB before 2.6, you must upgrade to 2.6 before >upgrading to 3.0. See Upgrade to 2.6 for the procedure to upgrade from 2.4 to >2.6. Once upgraded to MongoDB 2.6, you cannot downgrade to any version earlier >than MongoDB 2.4."

In a previous project, we had to upgrade from 2.6.8 -> 3.0 (upgrade members in a rolling manner to keep the cluster up and running). Our rollback plan was to decide at this point whether everything was OK and if not rollback to 2.6.8. If it was ok, upgrade from 3.0 -> 3.2 (again, a rolling upgrade). We did not try a two step downgrade, but I guess it is theoretically possible based on what Mongo documents. From 3.4, you will have to review the release notes to see if it is theoretically possible!

Also note that you need to consider upgrading your client drivers along the way. There are compatibility issues with client driver versions as well.

Comment: Yes, I saw the documentation! I decided against adding a 3.4 seed member to the existing 2.6.8 replica sets, it didn't make sense to, based on the docs.  But it made sense that a Mongo 3.0.x member would be compatible to add to a replica set containing members on 2.6.8.  So I added a 3.0.15 seed member - this was successful, or has been so far!  Thank you for your response.